# Issues recording video

Tags: android, video, camera, codec, recording

I have an application that records video in Android without issues in most of the phones and API levels. The code to record is the following:

```
recorder.setCamera(cam);
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER); 
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
if(Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) > 7){
   CamcorderProfile mProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
   recorder.setProfile(mProfile);
}else{
   recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
   recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
   recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
}
recorder.setOutputFile(path);
recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

For an unknown reason when this code executes in a Motorola Model MB632 running Android 2.3.5 I get the following errors in the Logcat:

```
OMXCodec      : Buffer count/size less than minimum required
OMXCodec      : Allocate Buffer failed - error = -2147483648
Media Recorder: start failed: -12
Camera        : Error 100
Application   : frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/MPEG4Writer.cpp:2966 mCodecSpecificData
```

And returns an exception. I have tried all kind of combinations and the buffer size does not seem to be something that you can change from the API functions.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532554/trouble-trying-to-get-mediarecorder-to-work-correctly, see the comment

Comment: I read that already but did not help much. It seems that some cameras don't follow the normal programming. I have even broken it down by API level as you can see but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question but I ran into a very similar problem on an HTC Evo (PC36100) running 2.3.5. I noticed that SpyCamera (https://bitbucket.org/jimmod/spy-camera-os) did work on this device. After reviewing the code I noticed that I was not setting the preview size, preview format, and focus mode while SpyCamera was. I added code to set these values and it I stopped getting the Error 100 when I started recording.

```
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();          

params.setPreviewSize(640, 480);
params.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
if (params.getSupportedFocusModes().contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
    params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
}
camera.setParameters(params);
```